# Remove rows from SAS dataset with specific date range

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

There are 2 datasets. I want a Final_Output dataset with all the rows that is only in Dataset_A not in Dataset_B.
Also, In Dataset_B date can be in range +8 or -8 to the date in Dataset_A.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Here, Account_no 324 with Date 21-Jan-21 and amount $10 is a match in Dataset_B ( Dataset_A.Date is +8 greater than or -8 smaller than the date in Dataset_B.Date ) .

As in images. Highlighted color are removed and left over are Final_Output.

Comment: Please post data as text and show what you've tried please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and let me know if this is what you are looking for. I did it in 2 steps to help you understand the logic, you can condense into one step as well.

The first step will join all the data in B that matches your criteria with A.
The second step will delete the matched ones, and keep the rest.

```
proc sql;
create table Temp as
    select a.*, b.account_no as B_Account_No
from Dataset_A A left join Dataset_B B 
    on a.Account_no = b.Account_no 
        and intnx('day', a.Date, -8) < b.Date < intnx('day', a.Date, +8)
;quit;

data Final;
set Temp;
    where B_Account_no = .;
drop B_Account_no ;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution actually works for me.